# Can't free a Malloc'd string

Tags: c, string, malloc

This one should be quick, I think.

EDIT: This is for my CS113 class. I just needed to free all the memory. If Valgrind found any memory leaks, I'd lose points. :P

Regardless, I figured out that it apparently just required me to free stuff in Main that related to the return value of zero_pad. Once I did so, it worked fine. I'd mark this post as "complete" if I knew how.

```
char *zero_pad(struct cpu_t *cpu, char *string)
{
    char *zero_string = malloc(cpu->word_size + 1); 
    int num_zeros = ((cpu->word_size) - strlen(string));
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num_zeros; i++)
    {
        zero_string[i] = '0';
    }

    return strncat(zero_string, string, strlen(string));    
}
```

I need to free zero_string, since I allocated it. However, I have no idea how. 
If I free it before I return, then I've lost that data and can't return it. If I try to free it after, the function has already returned and thus can't go on to freeing it.

I tried to use strcpy to copy the string in zero_string into a new string, but I must have been doing it wrong, because I just ended up with a massive mess.

So, what do you all think?

Comment: It's not uncommon for API documentation to mention that the caller is responsible for `free`ing the return value.

Comment: I have no idea what that means man. Pretty new here, this is my first semester of CS113. Love it so far though!

Comment: `int num_zeros = ((cpu->word_size) - strlen(string));` contains a signed-unsigned error

Comment: Whoever calls zeropad must free the returned buffer when they're done with it.

Comment: You'll have to free it after. The catch is that you don't have to change anything about `zero_pad` itself. Just mention in the documentation of your code that, whenever someone calls `zero_pad`, they'll have to make sure that they make the call to `free`.

Comment: I just called zero_pad from main. So, I can free it from main? I'll try that next. :D

Comment: "If I try to free it after, the function has already returned and thus can't go on to freeing it". That's not the case. The function is returning a pointer to the buffer. So the caller of the function can free it. `malloc` and `free` do not have to be done in the same function.

Comment: EDIT: This is for a project in class. One of the requirments is that everything is freed at the end and there are no memory leaks. I'll update OP so it's clear

Comment: `strncat` is used incorrect here: the first argument must be a null-terminated string. Better would be `strcpy(zero_string + i, string); return zero_string;`

Comment: SWEET! Got it working! I just needed to free the variables that were made from zero_pad in main. I set a variable called e1 and e2 to something regarding zero_pad's output. Once I freed those two, it freed the rest as well. So it's all working! No memory leaks detected by Valgrind.

Comment: @TylerShellberg Yes, you can. If you `malloc` something, you don't have to necessarily `free` it in the *same* function. Any memory object you `malloc` is owned by a process (not just by a function in the process), and can be `free`d by that process. The only reason why there's this rule about "you shall `free` what you `malloc`" is to conserve precious resources.

Comment: There are several ways to return a pointer to a string from a function -- and all of them are annoying. You can have the function allocate space  using `malloc`, which makes the caller responsible for calling `free()`. Or you can return a pointer to a `static` character array -- which means that later calls will clobber the string returned by previous calls, and it places a fixed upper bound on the size of the string. Or the caller can allocate space for the string and pass in a pointer to it -- which makes the caller responsible for allocating the memory (and knowing how much is needed).

Comment: @KeithThompson Doesn't the use of a static character array after the call completed cause UB?

Comment: @Rhymoid: No. The point of `static` (when used inside a function) is that it gives the object *static storage duration*, which means that the object's lifetime is the entire execution of the program. It also means that there's only one copy of the array, rather than one copy per call.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was thinking of something else. Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

What is `cpu->word_size` ? Are you sure that `cpu->word_size >= strlen(string)` in any case ?

Anyway, the returned buffer is mallocated so it is the caller's responsibility to free it. Another possibility is to use a static variable if you know the maximum size needed. This is the code.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 128 /* adjust this */
char *zero_pad(struct cpu_t *cpu, char *string)
{
    static char zero_string[MAX_SIZE]; 
    int num_zeros = ((cpu->word_size) - strlen(string));
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num_zeros; i++)
    {
        zero_string[i] = '0';
    }

    strcpy(zero_string + i, string); 
    return zero_string;   
}
```

Obviously, the caller should be informed that the returned buffer is always the same (the caller has to duplicate the returned buffer if needed, e.g. using `strdup()` and later `free()`).