# Cannot malloc and then goto top of program

Tags: c, malloc, goto

Been working at this for several hours. I've been absolutely stumped.

This is a lab for CS113.

If the user, at the end of the program (a binary calculator) chooses to continue, we need to use a goto statement to get to the top of the program.

However, we also need to free all allocated memory.

These two things seem to be incompatible. If I free the allocated memory and the user chooses to continue, everything goes absolutely bonkers. Even though the values are re-initialized, then somehow get screwed up in the process. I'm really sorry but I don't know how to explain it better than that. It seems like they end up getting filled with junk, even though the steps are identical as the first run though.

The code I have is below. Note that the "Free allocated memory" section is commented out in my version, but I left it here so there wouldn't be confusion.

**EDIT: The CPU can be freed now. The current version, as it stands, works. However, I cannot free the string I allocated, or the registers made of doubly linked lists. The free functions that I cannot use are commented out, and towards the end of the program.**

**NOTE: THE PROGRAM WORKS ABSOLUTELY FINE, EVEN ACROSS MULTIPLE RUNS IF THE MEMORY ISN'T FREED AT THE END. PLEASE NOTE THAT.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> 
#include"lab9.h"
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    struct cpu_t *cpu = NULL;

    top: 

    if(cpu)
    {
        free(cpu);
        cpu = NULL;
    }

    cpu = malloc(sizeof(struct cpu_t));

    if(!cpu) /* Error check malloc for CPU */
        {
                printf("Sorry! Malloc failed to allocate space for the CPU!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }  

    struct bit_t *temp1 = cpu->r1_head;
    struct bit_t *temp2 = cpu->r2_head;
    struct bit_t *temp3 = cpu->r3_head; 

    /* Setting all flags to 0 by default */
    cpu->overflow = 0;
    cpu->carry = 0;
    cpu->sign = 0;
    cpu->parity = 0;
    cpu->zero = 0;

    char buffer[128];
    char unsign; /* Holds a char: 0 for signed, 1 for unsigned */
    char *expression = NULL; /* Binary expression */
    char *e1 = NULL; /* Holds the first part of the expression */
    char op; /* Holds the operand */
    char *e2 = NULL; /* Holds the second part of the expression */
    char ans; /* y if user wants to continue, else ends program */
    int temp = 0; /* Used for printing separating dashes */
    int one_count = 0; /* Number of ones in the result */  

        printf("\nPlease enter the word size: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        cpu->word_size = atoi(buffer); /* atoi takes a pointer, don't dereference buffer*/

        while(cpu->word_size < 1 || cpu->word_size > 64) /* Error check word size */
        {
                printf("Error: Word size must be between 1 and 64. \n");
                printf("Enter a new word size: \n");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
                cpu->word_size = atoi(buffer);
        }

        printf("Are the values unsigned? [Y/N]: ");

        unsign = *fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); /* fgets returns address to data, must be dereferenced */

    switch(unsign)
    {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        cpu->unsign = 1;    
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        cpu->unsign = 0;
        break;
    }

        printf("Please enter the binary expression: ");

    expression = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); /* Stores expression in string */

    e1 = strtok(expression, " "); /* Breaks off first number*/

    switch(check_string(cpu, e1)) /* Error check first string */
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Error in input: Length of operand greater than word size. \n");
        printf("Error in first operand. Retry. \n");
        goto top;
    case 2:
        printf("Error in input: Something other than a 1 or 0 entered. \n");
        printf("Error in first operand. Retry. \n");
        goto top;
    default:
        break;
    }

    e1 = zero_pad(cpu, e1); /* Zero pads first number */

    op = *strtok(NULL, " "); /* Operation (+, -, ^, &, |) */

    e2 = strtok(NULL, " \n"); /* Original string had \n at end. Otherwise length would be 1 over actual. */

    switch(check_string(cpu, e2)) /* Error check second string */
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Error in input: Length of operand greater than word size. \n");
        printf("Error in second operand. Retry. \n");
        goto top;
    case 2:
        printf("Error in input: Something other than a 1 or 0 entered. \n");
        printf("Error in second operand. Retry. \n");
        goto top;
    default:
        break;
    }

    e2 = zero_pad(cpu, e2); /* Zero pads second number */

    create_r1(cpu, e1);
    create_r2(cpu, e2);
    create_r3(cpu);

    switch(op)
    {
    case '+':
        add_function(cpu);
        break;
    case '-':
        op = '+';
        complement(cpu); /* Turns second expression into 2's complement of itself */
        add_function(cpu);
        break;
    case '&':
        and_function(cpu);
        break;
    case '|':
        or_function(cpu);
        break;
    case '^':
        xor_function(cpu);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error in operator. Please retry. \n");
        goto top;
    }

    temp1 = cpu->r1_head;
    temp2 = cpu->r2_head;
    temp3 = cpu->r3_head;   

    /* Print the first register */
    while(temp1)
    {
        printf("%d", temp1->n);
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
    puts("");

    /* Print operator */
    printf("%c\n", op);

    /* Print second register */
    while(temp2)
    {
        printf("%d", temp2->n);
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    puts("");

    /* Print spacing dashes */
    while(temp < (cpu->word_size))
    {
        printf("-");
        temp++;
    }
    puts("");

    /* Print third register (stores answer) */
    while(temp3)
    {
        printf("%d", temp3->n);
        temp3 = temp3->next;
    }
    puts("");

    /* Flag handling */

    /* Reset temp variables */
    temp1 = cpu->r1_head;
    temp2 = cpu->r2_head;
    temp3 = cpu->r3_head;   

    /* Flag handling */
    if(temp3->n == 1)
    {
        cpu->sign = 1;
    }

    while(temp3)
    {
        if(temp3->n == 1)
        {
            one_count++;
        }
        temp3 = temp3->next;
    }

    if(one_count == 0)
    {
        cpu->zero = 1;
    }
    else if(one_count % 2 == 0)
    {
        cpu->parity = 1;
    }

    printf("Flags: \n");
    printf("Overflow:         %d \n", cpu->overflow);
    printf("Carry:            %d \n", cpu->carry);
    printf("Sign:             %d \n", cpu->sign);
    printf("Parity:           %d \n", cpu->parity);
    printf("Zero:             %d \n", cpu->zero);
    printf("Decimal:      %d \n", find_decimal(cpu));

    printf("Do you want to continue? [Y/N] \n"); /* If not 'y' or 'Y', close program */
    ans = *fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    /* Reset temps...again */
    temp1 = cpu->r1_head;
    temp2 = cpu->r2_head;
    temp3 = cpu->r3_head;   

    /* Free all allocated memory */
    //delete_list(cpu->r1_head);
    //delete_list(cpu->r2_head);
    //delete_list(cpu->r3_head);

    /* Free zero_string */
    //free(e1);
    //free(e2);

    if(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
    {
        temp = 0;
        goto top;
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to construct a minimal test case (aka MCVE), by removing all the stuff that's not relevant to your problem?

Comment: Are you under specific instruction to use a `goto`, because there otherwise is no reason to use one.

Comment: You should be using a function to dump a register, rather than writing out the same code multiple times.  And while `puts("");` does output a newline, so too does `putchar('\n');` — though I note a trend where the character I/O functions are not used as much as they used to be.

Comment: Does the function `zero_pad()` actually allocate memory?  You use it as `e1 = zero_pad(cpu, e1);` and then you later do `free(e1);`.  If `zero_pad()` does not allocate memory for `e1`, when you free it, you are freeing unallocated memory, which inevitably leads to tremendous trouble.  Is [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) an option for you?  If so, use it!

Comment: You could simplify your code by using `struct cpu_t cpu;` instead of malloc

Comment: Replacing `goto top;` with `main();`would avoid any issues with goto (not that there should be any in this case)

Comment: I wonder if `zero_pad` is actually the same function from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927659/cant-free-a-mallocd-string)  which contains a buffer overflow, as I pointed out in comments...   said overflow could cause heap corruption resulting in the observed problems with `free`.

Comment: The code also uses the result of `strtok` and `fgets` without first checking for `NULL`, causing undefined behaviour if they were in fact null.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. I've been at it all  day today and haven't figured out exactly how to free memory. I might just submit the assignment as is, I'm exhausted. That "Zero_pad" function is indeed mine. If it has any issues, they don't show up when running it. Again, the program runs perfectly fine, I just can't free all my memory at the end manually. I don't really care about error-checking strtok or fgets, we're told we'll get error-free input of a specific format in this lab.

Comment: @TylerShellberg I've pointed out a serious bug twice which you appear to be ignoring ...  (the buffer overflow in zero_pad)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change the beginning of main to something like this:

```
int main() {
    struct cpu_t *cpu = NULL;
top:
    if (cpu) {
        free(cpu);
        cpu = NULL;
    }
    cpu = malloc(sizeof(struct cpu_t));
```

Comment: I'll try this. Gimme a few minutes, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Upon trying this, the first run-through is OK, but the second time through I get this error: "double free or curroption" (fasttop) Aborted (core dumped)"

Comment: notice how I reset cpu to NULL.  If you don't do that, cpu will still point to the memory location of the previous allocation.  Then your code at the top will try to free it again.  You need to do the reset to NULL after freeing in C.

Comment: I did set it to Null. Wait, do I need to delete freeing the CPU at the end of the program? I figured your change was just to the top since you said "Change to the beginning"

Comment: EDIT: I deleted the line later on at the end of the program that freed CPU. I suppose I should do the same thing for all the other mallocs as well. It doesnt' have that double-free issue now though. Still broken, but I think it's making progress.

Comment: EDIT: I tried to do it for the rest of them, but now it just seg-faults when I try to run it. I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: This is a horrible style of coding and also wouldn't help with the problem

Comment: I'm extremely new man. It's my first semester of CS113. Cut me some slack. This lab has taken far more hours than any other, and I've gotten it incredibly close to working. If I can just figure out this freeing stuff, It'll be done.

Comment: Sorry, I got you messed up.  I think you only need to have your frees at the top.  Runtime would automatically clean up your memory on exit, but you can free if after the goto top line.  You could maybe consolidate your frees all into a single function if that makes any sense.  It would make your logic a little cleaner.

Comment: Bruceg, I just put the latest version of the program up at the top. As it stands, it works. However, I need to comment out the functions that free my registers, and the one that frees e1 and e2 (which were made up partially of malloced memory). How would I go about fixing those ones? Also, I need to have ALL memory freed at the end of the program. It's just one of the requirements. If I put it all at the top, I'm concerned that it wont free all the memory and I'll be screwed. :c